# Is SELECT FOR UPDATE Even Necessary

Tags: mysql, select-for-update

I'm reposting this important question (deemed duplicate) because similar previous posts do not concisely answer the question of: is SELECT FOR UPDATE even necessary? For example, what is the difference between

```
BEGIN;
SELECT * FROM kv WHERE k = 1 FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE kv SET v = v + 5 WHERE k = 1;
COMMIT;
```

and

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE kv SET v = v + 5 WHERE k = 1;
COMMIT;
```

Doesn't the second case lock the required row before performing the update, anyway?  Furthermore, the first case is useless in mid-transactions as there could be substantial time period between SELECT and UPDATE execution, resulting in long lock waits.

Comment: The difference is that you can get the values from before the update in the first version.

Comment: If you don't need to do that, there's no need for the `SELECT`.

Comment: You might use `SELECT FOR UPDATE` if you want to show the users the rows, ask them if it's OK to add 5, then do the update.

Comment: @Barmar no, user interaction should never happen mid-transaction.  but you might want to lock them, read some other data, and update based on that data

Comment: @ysth Yeah, I was trying to give a more concrete example, even though it's not what you would actually do.

Comment: The application might want to display a before/after difference. So it does the SELECT FOR UPDATE, saves the results, does the update, SELECTs the new data.